# Proof of $\Bbb{N}$ is inductive

Tags: real-numbers

Here [there is](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Natural_Numbers_form_Inductive_Set) a proof
 but I think it is incomplete(missing $1\in\Bbb{N}$)

Note:
A⊆R is inductive if and only if 1∈A and ∀x∈A⇒x+1∈A.

By definition, $\Bbb{N}$ is the intersection of all inductive sets

I tried to do a proof here:

$\Bbb{N} = \bigcap A_i\in I$ : $1 \in A_i \land \forall x\in A_i \Rightarrow x+1 \in A_i$

This is the same as:

$\Bbb{N} = \{x: x\in A_1 \land x\in A_2 \land x \in A_3 \land ...\}$

As $1 \in A_i\in I \Rightarrow 1\in \bigcap A_i\in I $ ie $1\in \Bbb{N}$

the rest is same

Is my proof correct?

Comment: 1 is in N by definition of intersection.  1 is in all A_i so 1 is in the intersection.

Comment: The set of inductive sets is not countable.  So ... no ... I don't think your proof works.

Comment: Leave off the indexes.  Simple say N = $\cap A; A \in I$ and $\forall A \in I; 1 \in A$ and therefore $1 \in N =\cap A$.  Then your proof is good.